# Javascript Garbage collection for inline code

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, garbage-collection

We've In-Line Javascript data like following with thousand of lines.
I've observed that it is taking lot of memory too, this is a problem in mobile browsers.
Does it help to move this code to some JSON File, and parsing it.
I just want this code to GCed as soon as it is executed.

```
 db.transaction(function(tx) {
     transaction.executeSql("INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES(111,'xxx','2012-11-09 18:48:12')");
     ..... Another 10K Lines of above String .............
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With about 10k of those lines, you have about half a MB of raw text going through your js, not to mention the fact that you're calling `transaction.executeSql()` about 10k times.

You could reduce that a bit by combining multiple (/all) `INSERT INTO` statements into a single statement:

```sql
INSERT INTO
    TABLE
VALUES
    (111,'xxx','2012-11-09 18:48:12'),
    (222,'yyy','2012-11-09 18:48:12'),
    (333,'zzz','2012-11-09 18:48:12')
    etc...
```

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful.
We can a load Javascript file on-demand, Is there a way to unload it too ?

Comment: How are you loading the file?

Comment: Some files are getting loaded with Script tag, But some are loaded with JQuery Mobile Framework

Comment: You could have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781406/unload-external-js-file It doesn't seem like there's a specific function for it, though.