# Only load a javascript file depending on screen size

Tags: javascript, html, responsive-design

I'm working on making a website responsive. For now the website will have to have two banners- one for desktop and one fro the mobile site.

I've got everything in place with media querys etc. however I've now noticed that something in the `desktop banner javascript file` is causing the `mobile banner javascript` to not function properly.

So I figured I could try to only load the `desktop banner js file` only if the screen is above a certain size, let's say 1000px.

I'm not sure if that's possible though and how? Or is there some other way to cancel out the `desktop js file` when the mobile banner is displayed?

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Why not use media queries for the image instead?

Comment: This is very unproductive. Try to do media queries (99% of the issues can be solved by this) or if you really want to do this, try using the `height` and `width` window properties in JavaScript to run pieces/functions of your code. Use this as a reference http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_innerheight.asp

Comment: DO NOT selectively load JavaScript based on screen size. You'd cause network thrashing when resizing a browser, and there is no way the savings of removing the few bytes of JS to a separate file is worth it.

Comment: I would heavily recommend you finding why desktop banner js file is breaking the mobile banner js file. Anything beyond seems hacky including my answer below

Answer (score 4):

```
if (window.innerWidth < 1000) {
   ... mobile banner code
} else {
   ... desktop banner code
}
```

And if user resizes the window, you are on your own :)

Comment: That's why you should use `screen`, not `window`, you can't resize the screen

Comment: @JuanMendes I sure can resize the screen.

Comment: I can resize the screen on my cellphone literally by just holding it differently (in some apps, that is).

Comment: You should not design based on screen, if user has a wide screen but keeps the browser small, you should render accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `screen.width` in Javascript

```
if (screen.width > 1000) {
//load file for screen width 1000 and up here
} else {
//load file for screen width under 1000 here
}
```

This loads only one of the two files, depending on screen size.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to load a `JavaScript file`, you can detect the user agent with `navigator.userAgent` and load a different script for mobile and other users:

```js
function isMobile() {
  return (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent));
}


function loadScript(url) {
  var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.src = url;
  head.appendChild(script);
}

if (isMobile()) {
  loadScript("MOBILE-script.js");
  console.log("mobile script");
} else {
  loadScript("DESKTOP-script.js");
  console.log("desktop script");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set up flags depending on the window size, everything dimensions information you will need is in the snippet above.

```
var w = window,
    d = document,
    e = d.documentElement,
    g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
    x = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth,
    y = w.innerHeight|| e.clientHeight|| g.clientHeight;
```

Keep in mind that you may need to bind script loading on a resize event handler.
I highly recommend using a [debouncing](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/throttled-smartresize-jquery-event-handler/) pipe function in order to handle resizing more efficiently.

Afterwards you can load scripts using some utility functions as:

```
function loadScript(url, callback) {
  // Adding the script tag to the head as suggested before
  var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = url;

  // Then bind the event to the callback function.
  // There are several events for cross browser compatibility.
  script.onreadystatechange = callback;
  script.onload = callback;

  // Fire the loading
  head.appendChild(script);
}

if (x > 1000) {
  //desktop
  loadScript("desktop.js", myPrettyCode);
} else {
  //mobile tablet
    loadScript("mobile.js", myPrettyCode);
}
```

Keep in mind that utility libraries like Modernizr have some useful feature detection helpers that may help you. David Walsh has also [provided a quite smart way](https://davidwalsh.name/device-state-detection-css-media-queries-javascript) to detecting screen sizes.
Also , unloading a script is pretty harsh [here is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781406/unload-external-js-file) a relevant StackOverflow question

You may also take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file) as it may be helpful as well as taking a look at [require.js](http://requirejs.org/) , it's an efficient JavaScript file and module loader.

Answer (score 0):

Screen size can be retrieved using

```
screen.availWidth // 1920
screen.availHeight // 1112
```