# Loading different scripts depending on screensize

Tags: javascript

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34902833/14773450

In this answer, would I be right in assuming that if I wanted to load a certain script ONLY for (say) iPhone, then I could delete some of the entries within isMobile()?

i.e. :

```
function isMobile() {
   return (/iPhone/i.test(navigator.userAgent));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes that would be correct because the code is still syntactically correct and it would rule out all other devices like androids

Comment: Thanks Da. Good to know!

Comment: If it's the correct answer, please mark it as so, so that the question can be closed